# Getting user details when click on username link that in a table . I want to write a single dynamic file

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, sql

I want a single dynamic file that will get username when we click on username link.
I have created a table where there are lots of name all name are link . I want to get user details dynamically I mean on which name I click I get only that user details . If I click on another user name I will get their details.
All user details must come from a data base.

Here is my code how make a table of names where all names are link.

Can anybody help me out by some dynamic code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            .green {
                background: #4DDB4D;
                color: black;
            }
            .red {
                background: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
</html>
<?php 
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","db_dat");
    $havepassport='';
    $sql = "SELECT * from upload WHERE having_passport='yes' OR having_passport='no'";
    $result = $conn -> query($sql);
    $havepassport='';
    $havepassport .='<table>';
    $havepassport .='<tr>'.'<th>'."Name".'</th>'.'<th>'."Having Passport".'</th>'.'</tr>';


    while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
        $passportClass = $row['having_passport'] == 'yes' ? 'green' : 'red';

        $havepassport .='<tr class='.$passportClass.'>'.'<td>';
        $havepassport .= '<a href="">'. $row['emp_name'].'</a>';
        $havepassport .= '</td>'.'<td>'. $row['having_passport'].'</td>'.'</tr>';
    }
    $havepassport.='</table>';
    echo $havepassport;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to only get details for only one person, that would really be quite simple, you just change your SQL query to look for one person using some unique identifier you pass to the script, most commonly, the user id.

```
$sql = "SELECT * from upload WHERE user_id=:user_id (having_passport='yes' OR having_passport='no')";
$statementHandler->prepare($sql);
$statementHandler->bindParam(':employee_id', $userId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statementExecute();
```

Then you can go on and display your page as you normally would, but you would only get one row from your query, determined from the unique identifier you pass the script. A common convention for this is to put a link into the table you are already generating that will link to each individual user

```
<a href="{some_url}/employees/{employee_id}/view">{employee_name}</a>
```

The same principle can be applied when doing other CRUD operations.
If you want to use javascript for this, you can simply make an ajax call to the script and pass it the unique identifier and have that fetch the call for you, and then parse the data within javascript in any way you'd like.